# How do I make Grails Fixtures plugin make use of Fongo to run integration test faster?

Tags: mongodb, grails, integration-testing, grails-2.0, spock

We use mongodb for our grails application. When looking for in memory mongodb implementations we stumbled upon https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo.

1. Is it possible for http://grails.org/plugin/fixtures to use it?
2. Are there better alternatives/better solution?